# Rails: Two level route renders root page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am having some problems creating a route to my app, please help me :)

Can anyone explain to me why a two level route renders my root page, no matter if the route really exists or not.

Let me exemplify:

I have the route:
`match '/p/novo' => 'user_roles#new', :as => :new_urole`

I expected the new method from the `user_roles` method to be called, but it doesnt happen. Instead of it, my root page gets rendered and the log shows:

> Started GET "/p/novo" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-04 16:50:23 -0300
>   Processing by HomeController#index as HTML

If i remove the '/novo' from the route, everything works!

Can anyone help me?

Edit:
I dont know why, but i placed the route above a route that linked to my root and it worked

My `rake:routes` **WORKING**

```
                    /auth/:provider/callback(.:format)                               session#create
        login_erro  /login/erro(.:format)                                            session#failure
            logout  /logout(.:format)                                                session#destroy
         new_urole  /p/novo(.:format)                                                user_roles#new
             event  /evento/:day/:month/:year/:url_name(.:format)                    events#show
                    /evento/:day/:month/:year/:url_name/confirmar_presenca(.:format) events#confirm_presence
painel_de_controle  /painel_de_controle(.:format)                                    users#control_panel
        city_index  /:state/:city(.:format)                                          home#index
              root  /                                                                home#index
```

Comment: Can you run `rake routes` and post the output?

Comment: Can you post your rake routes output including methods, GET POST etc. and also your routes.rb file

Answer (score 0):

new_urole is not a GET route, it's likely a POST or PUT route. This is why it's not matching, your request is GET so it falls down all the way to the first GET route that matches, root.

You need to change your form :method to match your route method, POST or PUT.

Comment: i dont think thats it, because i tested my route like this and it didnt work:
> get '/p/novo' => 'user_roles#new', :as => :new_role